# What is the difference between "созревать" and "поспевать"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I mean,

> "В огороде на грядке **созрела** клубника"

and

> "В огороде на грядке **поспела** клубника".

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Поспеть** has two different meanings:

- **созреть**, стать годным для еды (to become edible) and
- **успеть** (to be in time) - this one is a bit outdated nowadays.

The word **созреть** mean mostly the same: for fruits it means the same as **поспеть**. It also means *to become mature*, etc.

In your example both words mean the same.

Answer (score 3):

I believe поспевать is somewhat more colloquial. Созревать is more standard Russian.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in this case.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, we usually prefer more expanded answers over a one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the first means "mature", and the second means "ripen"; but in this context they have exactly the same meaning, i.e. "ripen".

Answer (score 0):

Both words are used equally often and have the same meaning. But I think the second one better, because it has no another meaning. `Спелый` only means "ripe", while you can say `Зрелый` applying not only to vegetables or fruits, but also to people. `Зрелый мужчина` means `mature (or verile) man`